# gitolite3: Change a normal repo into a wild repo?

Tags: gitolite

I have created about 20 repos by manual entries:

```
repo u1
    RW+ = u1

repo u2
    RW+ = u2
...
```

Now I have noticed, that I could have used:

```
@u = u1 u2
repo CREATOR
    C = @u
    RW+ = CREATOR
    R = READERS
    RW = WRITERS
```

Is there an easy way to switch from the upper normal repos to the wild card repos?

(Of course, now I notice, that I should have used something like `user/CREATOR/..*` but there is no easy way without annoying 20 users)

Comment: AFAIK, wildcard repos need a wildcard in their definition or they are not recognized by gitolite as wildcard repos. For instance, I wanted to allow everybody to be able to make a repo with a name the same as their username. `repo   users/CREATOR` didn't work, but `repo   user[s]/CREATOR` did. I do not know how you can apply to just `repo CREATOR` though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [gitolite manual mentions](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/basic-admin/#appendix-1-bringing-existing-repos-into-gitolite):

> If the repos are wildcard repos that already match some repo regex in the conf file, you need to manually create the `gl-creator` file, like so:
>
> ```
> echo username > ~/repositories/path/to/repo.git/gl-creator
> ```
>
> I haven't yet found this to be common enough to bother wrapping it in a nice interface or command.

So you can try and test at least for one repo:

- the wildcard syntax you mention in your answer
- adding `gl-creator` file (with the right username as its content) in the *existing* repo.git you would be using for that test. (Meaning with a repo which existed before trying to reference it as a wildcard repo)